# Apple Software Update catalog URL

Tags: macos, software-update

I was recently testing our internal SUS but am wanting to get back over to the beta update catalog (one used to get 10.10.1 beta) but did not make a backup. Does anyone have this or know where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer on my own.

Catalog URL: http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.10seed-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog